# SQL Server - hyphen in dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I want to execute a stored procedure which takes 2 arguments. The first argument is always `'%'` and the second is the last working date. If today is monday, then the last working date is friday, if today is tuesday then the last working date is monday and so on.

I want to also add `'` before and after the date which is being replaced dynamically.

I came up with this code:

```
declare @passPar datetime
declare @ppv nvarchar(100)
set @passPar =  case 
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 1 then  convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-2,getDate()),101) 
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 2 then convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-3,getDate()),101) 
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 3 then convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-1,getDate()),101)
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 4 then convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-1,getDate()),101)
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 5 then convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-1,getDate()),101)
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 6 then convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-1,getDate()),101)
end
set @ppv = N' Execute spCreateReports '%' + ''' @passPar '''
;
Execute spCreateReports '%', @passPar
```

If i just remove the `@ppv` I can then execute it as ;
`Execute spCreateReports '%', @passPar` which translates into , for example,  `Execute spCreateReports '%', 2016-04-27` but the **desired result** is  `Execute spCreateReports '%', '2016-04-27'`

**The original SQL code** I was using (and not working in SSIS but looks ok in SQL server) is:

```
declare @passPar datetime
set @passPar =  case 
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 1 then convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-2,getDate()),101) 
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 2 then convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-3,getDate()),101) 
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 3 then convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-1,getDate()),101)
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 4 then convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-1,getDate()),101)
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 5 then convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-1,getDate()),101)
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 6 then convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-1,getDate()),101)
end
;
Execute spCreateReports '%', @passPar
```

Any idea on how to do this, would be great

**EDIT**:

working code below:

```
declare @passPar nvarchar(50)
set @passPar =  case 
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 1 then convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-2,getDate()),120) 
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 2 then convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-3,getDate()),120) 
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 3 then convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-1,getDate()),120)
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 4 then convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-1,getDate()),120)
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 5 then convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-1,getDate()),120)
when (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())) = 6 then convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,-1,getDate()),120)
end
;
Execute spCreateReports '%', @passPar
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  Why doesn't the second version work?  How does it fail when you use it?

Comment: Well, in SSIS, if I just execute the task with the 2nd version, nothing happens. It appears like it was correctly executed but the stored procedure is not really executed. I am thinking that maybe (even if it should work without `'` before and after the dates) I should add it.

Comment: Or the better question would have simply been: why doesn't that 2nd piece of code work in a SSIS SQL task (The connection is working since have another task of truncating a table and that works great)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I get it right, as the code doesn't even compile, but it looks like you assign dynamic sql to a variable and never execute it. Try adding EXEC(@ppv) at the end.

EDIT: for some reason I cannot answer in a comment, so I'll write here:

Try changing the @passPar data type, it should be declare @passPar nvarchar(10), and then you don't need to add any quotes, no dynamic sql, it should just work.

Comment: Try the original code (the second snippet of code). How would you alter that to output: `Execute spCreateReports '%', '2016-04-26'` ?

Comment: 10 is not mine, but yours idea, you convert dates to varchar(10) (just take a look at your code ;)), but then assign it to datetime variable, which dosn't make sense. if you convert to varchar, stick to varchar. Anyway, varchar is what your procedure expects.

Comment: you were right about the data type for @passPar . I also changed the way it is displayed as a date from style 101 to 120. Thanks